# Xpath query unexpectedly returns 0 in Java/groovy, works in other interpreter

Tags: java, xml, xpath, groovy, cucumber

I'm trying to create a Cucumber step definition in Groovy that finds a certain node in an XML document (a Solr search result) by the value of a mandatory 'url' tag and returns this node's position in the list of results.

This is my scenario:

```
    Given I seach for "pris"
    Then I should see this link in the results: "/7292/pris-forbruk-og-inntekt"
    Then I will see the position of this url: "/7292/pris-forbruk-og-inntekt"
```

This is my step definition:

```
Then(~'^I should see this link in the results: "([^"]*)"$') { String tekst ->
assertThat(browser.getPageSource(), containsString(tekst))
}

Then(~'^I will see the position of this url: "([^"]*)"$') { String text -> 

    pageSource = browser.getPageSource()

    //Prints the position of the relevant search result
    def xpathString = "count(/response/result/doc/str[.='" + text + "']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)"  //+1

    builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
    doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(pageSource.getBytes("utf-8"))))
    expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(xpathString)
    posisjon = expr.evaluate(doc)
    println "The position of this result is: " + posisjon.toString()
    println xpathString

}
```

Both tests return a green cuke, so I know that the string is found in the XML.
Here's an example of the XML result I'm evaluating:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">75</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">true</str>
            <str name="q">pris</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="306" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="url">/nasjonalregnskap/nokkeltall/priser-og-prisindekser</str>
            <str name="id">3730</str>
            <str name="tittel">Priser og prisindekser</str>
            <str name="innholdstype">nokkeltallsside</str>
            <date name="publiseringsdato">2010-11-23T11:35:00Z</date>
            <str name="hovedemner">Nasjonalregnskap</str>
            <str name="sprak">no</str>
            <str name="rom">statistikk</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <str name="url">/7292/pris-forbruk-og-inntekt</str>
            <str name="id">7292</str>
            <str name="tittel">Pris, forbruk og inntekt</str>
            <str name="innholdstype">publikasjon</str>
            <date name="publiseringsdato">2002-06-13T10:00:00Z</date>
            <str name="hovedemner">Befolkning</str>
            <str name="sprak">no</str>
            <str name="rom">statistikk</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

When I run this test (we're using Maven to build and run, so I have limited debugging options afaik) I get this output from the two println commands:

```
 The position of this result is: 0   
 count(/response/result/doc/str[.='/7292/pris-forbruk-og-inntekt']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)
```

However, when I evaluate this Xpath query to the exact same XML document in Altova XMLspy, I get the expected result!

Apparently I don't have enough reputation (sorry, sorry...) to post images, here's a link to a screenshot of [the result in Altova XMLspy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG6Gl.png)

So the question I can't figure out is: Does the Java XPathFactory evaluate xpath differently from other interpreters? Have I made a mistake or error in my implementation? The answer eludes me :)

Comment: According to the XML file, your query should return 0. Otherwise, it is not really the input XML.

Comment: I omitted too much of the xml, the file I'm working with has more hits and related info. I edited my submission, tested this on my system and it still gives the same result. Is my question clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually. I was probably implementing XPathFactory.Evaluate in an incorrect way.

Either way, I ended up using Gpath instead, this is the code I used to return the right result, in case someone comes along with a similar request in the future:

```
String pageSource = browser.getPageSource()

 def stream = new XmlSlurper().parseText(pageSource)
 List test = stream.depthFirst().findAll {it.@name=="url"}
 def pos = test.findIndexOf { it.toString().contains(tekst) } + 1

println pos
```

Tell the future I say hi ;)